# How to fix Compile error: Method or data member not found?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been asked to rewrite the below code using a worksheet object named shtCalculations. Directly below is the original code. The 2nd set of code is my rewritten code but when I try to run the macro it gives me the error "Compile error: Method or data member not found?". Then highlights Sub shtCalculations() in yellow and FormulaR1C1 in blue. What am I doing wrong? Thank you I am a novice just beginning to learn VBA in a class.

```
Sub workWithRanges2()

   'This is the first sheet in the first workbook that was open in your Excel application.
   'Workbook(1) can be different than the workbook where this code is runnig and different_
   'than the Active workbook.
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Activate
   'Clear the entire sheet.
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Cells.Clear
   'assign a random number between 1 and 6 to cell A2
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=Int((6 * Rand()) + 1)"
   'a different formula is assinged to cell B2, a random number between 1 and 20.
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=Int((20 * Rand()) + 1)"
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("A2:C2").Copy
   Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("A3:C10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

My rewritten code:

```
     Sub shtCalculations()
         'declare object variable and assign address'
         Dim shtFirst As Worksheet
         Set shtFirst = Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
         'Clear the entire sheet'
         shtFirst.Cells.Clear
         'assign a random number between 1 and 6 to cell A2'
         shtFirst.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=Int((6 * Rand()) + 1)"
         'a different formula is assigned to cell B2, a random number between 1 and 20'
         shtFirst.FormulaR1C1 = "=Int((20 * Rand()) + 1)"
         shtFirst.Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"
         shtFirst.Range("A2:C2").Copy
         shtFirst.Range("A3:C10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

     End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing `.Range("B2")` from that line.  `FormulaR1C1` is a property of `Range`, not of `Worksheet`  FYI seems like your `shtFirst` should be named `shtCalculations`

Comment: Thank you Tim it works now. I edited shtFirst to be named shtCalculations instead as well.

Comment: `Application.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)` isn't very specific.  That's just the first sheet in the first workbook you opened in the current session (at least I _think_ it's the first workbook you opened).  Could very easily be the wrong file & sheet and before you know it you've cleared all the cells from the wrong file & sheet.